# Randomly pick elements from a vector of counts

Tags: algorithm, matlab, statistics, octave

I'm currently trying to optimize some MATLAB/Octave code by means of an algorithmic change, but can't figure out how to deal with some randomness here. Suppose that I have a vector V of integers, with each element representing a count of some things, photons in my case. Now I want to randomly pick some amount of those "things" and create a new vector of the same size, but with the counts adjusted.

Here's how I do this at the moment:

```
function W = photonfilter(V, eff)
% W = photonfilter(V, eff)
% Randomly takes photons from V according to the given efficiency.
%
% Args:
%  V: Input vector containing the number of emitted photons in each
%     timeslot (one element is one timeslot). The elements are rounded
%     to integers before processing.
%  eff: Filter efficiency. On the average, every 1/eff photon will be
%       taken. This value must be in the range 0 < eff <= 1.
%  W: Output row vector with the same length as V and containing the number
%     of received photons in each timeslot.
%
% WARNING: This function operates on a photon-by-photon basis in that it
% constructs a vector with one element per photon. The storage requirements
% therefore directly depend on sum(V), not only on the length of V.

% Round V and make it flat.
Ntot = length(V);
V = round(V);
V = V(:);

% Initialize the photon-based vector, so that each element contains
% the original index of the photon.
idxV = zeros(1, sum(V), 'uint32');
iout = 1;
for i = 1:Ntot
  N = V(i);
  idxV(iout:iout+N-1) = i;
  iout = iout + N;
end;

% Take random photons.
idxV = idxV(randperm(length(idxV)));
idxV = idxV(1:round(length(idxV)*eff));

% Generate the output vector by placing the remaining photons back
% into their timeslots.
[W, trash] = hist(idxV, 1:Ntot);
```

This is a rather straightforward implementation of the description above. But it has an obvious performance drawback: The function creates a vector (idxV) containing one element per single photon. So if my V has only 1000 elements but an average count of 10000 per element, the internal vector will have 10 million elements making the function slow and heavy.

What I'd like to achieve now is not to directly optimize this code, but to use some other kind of algorithm which immediately calculates the new counts without giving each photon some kind of "identity". This must be possible somehow, but I just can't figure out how to do it.

Requirements:

- The output vector W must have the same number of elements as the input vector V.
- W(i) must be an integer and bounded by 0 <= W(i) <= V(i).
- The expected value of sum(W) must be sum(V)*eff.
- The algorithm must somehow implement this "random picking" of photons, i.e. there should not be some deterministic part like "run through V dividing all counts by the stepsize and propagating the remainders", as the whole point of this function is to bring randomness into the system.
- An explicit loop over V is allowed if unavoidable, but a vectorized approach is preferable.

Any ideas how to implement something like this? A solution using only a random vector and then some trickery with probabilities and rounding would be ideal, but I haven't had any success with that so far.

Thanks! Best regards, Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you employ to compute `W` is called [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method). And indeed there can be some optimizations. Once of such is instead of calculating indices of photons, let's imagine a set of bins. Each bin has some probability and the sum of all bins' probabilities adds up to 1. We divide the segment [0, 1] into parts whose lengths are proportional to the probabilities of the bins. Now for every random number within [0, 1) that we generate we can quickly find the bin that it belongs to. Finally, we count numbers in the bins to obtain the final result. The code below illustrates the idea.

```
% Population size (number of photons).
N = 1000000;
% Sample size, size of V and W as well.
% For convenience of plotting, V and W are of the same size, but
% the algorithm doesn't enforce this constraint.
M = 10000;
% Number of Monte Carlo iterations, greater numbers give better quality.
K = 100000;

% Generate population of counts, use gaussian distribution to test the method.
% If implemented correctly histograms should have the same shape eventually.
V = hist(randn(1, N), M);
P = cumsum(V / sum(V));
% For every generated random value find its bin and then count the bins.
% Finally we normalize counts by the ration of N / K.
W = hist(lookup(P, rand(1, K)), M) * N / K;
% Compare distribution plots, they should be the same.
hold on;
plot(W, '+r');
plot(V, '*b');
pause
```

[image]

Comment: With K=100K the drawn vector isn't that great, thought it still resembles the original shape. I suggest you to try with K=1M. Also the normalization isn't the best, I just couldn't come up with something better without introducing unnecessary complication to the example.

Comment: Great, thanks! I had to adapt it slightly to bring my "eff" coefficient into play (In fact, my K is not random but exactly the number of required photons). This makes the performance dependent on the number of output photons, but this is ok, since this will usually be much less than sum(V). If you agree, I will integrate my adaptations into your answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yes, sure! You also can send me your code and I will update the answer.

Comment: Ok, editing the answer was rejected as "makes no sense as an edit, make it an answer". That's what I'll do then, as I couldn't find a way to contact you directly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from Alexander Solovets, this is how the code now looks:

```
function W = photonfilter(V, eff, impl=1)

Ntot = length(V);
V = V(:);

if impl == 0
  % Original "straightforward" solution.
  V = round(V);
  idxV = zeros(1, sum(V), 'uint32');
  iout = 1;
  for i = 1:Ntot
    N = V(i);
    idxV(iout:iout+N-1) = i;
    iout = iout + N;
  end;
  idxV = idxV(randperm(length(idxV)));
  idxV = idxV(1:round(length(idxV)*eff));
  [W, trash] = hist(idxV, 1:Ntot);

else
  % Monte Carlo approach.
  Nphot = sum(V);
  P = cumsum(V / Nphot);
  W = hist(lookup(P, rand(1, round(Nphot * eff))), 0:Ntot-1);

end;
```

The results are quite comparable, as long as eff if not too close to 1 (with eff=1, the original solution yields W=V while the Monte Carlo approach still has some randomness, thereby violating the upper bound constraints).

Test in the interactive Octave shell:

```
octave:1> T=linspace(0,10*pi,10000);
octave:2> V=100*(1+sin(T));
octave:3> W1=photonfilter(V, 0.1, 0);
octave:4> W2=photonfilter(V, 0.1, 1);
octave:5> plot(T,V,T,W1,T,W2);
octave:6> legend('V','Random picking','Monte Carlo')
octave:7> sum(W1)
ans =  100000
octave:8> sum(W2)
ans =  100000
```

Plot:
[image: Plot]